# Usage of the word "or"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The word "or" is commonly used to link alternatives. For example, in the sentence "You should use a pencil or a pen", the meaning is you can choose which one you want to use.

However, as an example, if I wanted to say that I thought basketball was a better sport than both baseball and football, how would I word this?

Should I say, "I like basketball more than baseball or football." or "I like basketball more than baseball and football." Is there really even a difference in meaning between these two sentences? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The sense is "I like basketball better than [I like either] baseball or football." _Or_ is more usual, but there is no difference in meaning in this context.

Comment: You're up against DeMorgan's Laws, which state (among other things) that, for every pair of proposition (P, Q),  (NOT P AND NOT Q) is equivalent to NOT (P OR Q). You're using comparatives (_better, more_), which are negative triggers, hence the Law applies. See [The Logic Guide](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for further details.